# Plotting two sets of XY coordinates from same vector import file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, csv

I have written a QGIS plugin that creates a .CSV file and imports it into QGIS. In it there are two pairs of XY data in columns. I have the script to import the .CSV as a layer and specify one of these pairs (currently Target E/N).

Is it possible to also plot the second pair on the same layer, or do I need to import the .CSV as another layer and specify the second XY Pair - which is what I would have to do manually using the QGIS delimited import?

I'd like to import the .CSV once as a single layer, but plot both the Target E/N and the Actual E/N. I know I can put the Target and Actual in the same column, but that means I have to separate them again when I want to use the .CSV for other things later.

```
Name    Target E    Target N    Actual E    Actual N
Point1  527181.54   6755742.75  527191.54   6755750.75
Point2  525170.00   6756570.00  525180.00   6756578.00
Point3  528460.00   6764570.00  528470.00   6764578.00
Point4  530471.54   6763742.75  530481.54   6763750.75
```

My working code for the initial import and 'Target E/N' pair is below. Obviously I can repeat this with 'Actual E/N' but it creates a second layer, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

```
uri="file:///"+out_filename+"?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(",","Target E","Target N")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, project+"_Stations", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
my_crs=QgsProject.instance().crs().authid()
vlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(my_crs))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. In the symbology, add a new layer (press the green +),  set the type as Geometry Generator, make sure geometry type is point / multipoint and that unit is map unit and type in

```
 make_point("Actual E","Actual N")
```

[image: Symbology as set up, this is in Norwegian, but it should look similar]

Symbology as set up (This is in Norwegian, but it should look similar)

You may have to work a bit with the symbology to get something that works well in the map and in a possible legend.

[image: Crosses are targets, red dots are actual points]

Xs are target points, red dots are actual positions.

(Since I had no idea of the projection of your data set, I just set it to UTM33N which is the projection I am usually using)

As @Houska said in a comment, it is possible to add another geometry generator layer, set type to Line/Multiline and define it as

```
make_line($geometry,make_point("Actual E","Actual N"))
```

This would be helpful especially if the distances should be bigger so it is unclear which points belongs together,

Just beware that it is the initial points that are considered the geometry, so e.g. if you want to digitize something based on this layer, it is only possible to snap to the Target point, the actual point is just displayed.

Comment: That's an approach I hadn't considered (or even knew to be possible). As I need to create a 'Style' for this layer anyway, this is a very effective approach. I'm on a ship off the Norwegian coast, so your UTM isn't too unfamiliar.

Comment: You can also use the geometry generator to combine the 2. For instance, if you'd like a line linking the two, set the geometry type to line and use `make_line($geometry,make_point(...))` with the ... representing what's in the answer.

Comment: @WillH, discovering the Geometry Generator is one of the most "Wow!" moments I have had with QGIS, eg using it for plotting points with uncertainty.

Comment: Is there a way to then 'Categorize' the Geometry Generated point, or the Target one if I swap which I import first?

Comment: Just set it up as above and then classify it, the classification will use the initial symbol.